# XSS Bypass Whitelist

Tags: xss, html

I found a HTML injection on a markdown although it seems odd as the user already can use html in the box

[image]

So I tried to turn it to XSS but after a day with trial and error I concluded that the website has a whitelist that allows only  and  with specific attributes

`<img src=#>` anything after it will results in removing the whole payload

`<a href=javascript:alert(1)> will remove the :`

So I tried to bypass the colon that is removed with html and url encoding but with no success

The data is inserted into a a body of a div tag like this

> ``<div*>data here</div*>````

Any workarounds you think about?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the community. If you can "inject" HTML it doesn't mean that you can execute JS and so use XSS or similar...

Comment: Yes but I am trying to execute JS

Comment: Read my comment again then and think...